# Create new ui-grid by using a factory: what is the scope - parameter to use the ui-grid-event-handler?

Tags: angular-ui-grid, angularjs-factory

I create an ui-grid in my controller by using an Factory-method, which creates an new Table-Object(ui-grid). But I got problems with setting up the scope in the ui-grid-event-handlers.

See my    [js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/cnagel/6yzojwau/3/)    for better understanding.

In the jsfiddle you get now the error in the console:

`Cannot read property '$on' of undefined
    at Object.GridApi.registerEvent.feature.on.(anonymous function) [as navigate]`

If I change the handler-paramter to null, everything works fine, but...

In my project, which uses ui-router and by using null as gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate-parameter, I get the error in console:

`Cannot read property '$on' of undefined
    at Object.GridApi.registerEvent.feature.on.(anonymous function) [as navigate]`

Same error like above, but the parameter is self.scope!? But in my project,  using scope as Parameter, which get passed into the Table-Object, which is an reference to my $scope in my controller, which I don't use cause of ui-router an controllerAs-syntax, everything works fine. But in my opinion, reference this is not correct!?

> So my question is: Is anybody able to explain me, what should be the
>   first parameter for the gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate-handler!? Null,
>   scope, $scope, reference to scope-of controller...

If something is not clear, please give me a message and I try to give more infos.

Thanks a lot

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I use $scope and it works fine.